# GLGS: How do I "connect" a sampler to a texture?

Tags: opengl, glsl, geometry-shader

I am trying to read from a 3D texture inside a geometry shader:

```
#version 150

layout(points) in; // origo of cell
layout(points, max_vertices = 1) out;

uniform sampler3D text;

void main (void) 
{   
    for(int i = 0; i < gl_in.length(); ++i)
    {
        // texture coordinates:
        float u, v, w;

        // set u, v, and w somehow
        ...

        float value = texture(text, vec3(u, v, w)).r;

        bool show;

        // set show based on value somehow:
        ...

        if(show) {      
            gl_Position = gl_in[i].gl_Position;
            EmitVertex();
            EndPrimitive();  
        }  
    }
}
```

This is how I set up my texure inside my initialize GL code:

```
int nx = 101;
int ny = 101;
int nz = 101;
float *data = new float[nx*ny*nz];
// set data[] somehow:
...
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_3D);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D , texture); 
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_3D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
glTexImage3D( GL_TEXTURE_3D, 
                  0,      // level-of-detail number. 0 is the base image level.
             GL_RED, // internal format
         nx, ny, nz,
                  0,      // border
             GL_RED, // pixel format 
           GL_FLOAT,  // data type of the pixel data 
               data);
```

**But how do I associate the sampler "text" inside the geometry shader with my texture?**

So far I have not told OpenGL that there is a sampler named "text" and that it shall sample texture.

EDIT: I tried the following:

```
GLint textLoc = glGetUniformLocation(program, "text");
glUniform1i(textLoc, 0); // sends 0 to "text" in shader
// why do I not just hardcode 0 inside the geometry shader instead ? 
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_3D , texture); 
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0); // same as 0 ?
GLuint sampler_state = 0;
glGenSamplers(1, &sampler_state);
glBindSampler(0, sampler_state); // what does this do?
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: [Like this](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_%28GLSL%29#Binding_textures_to_samplers)

Comment: My compiler (VS2008) gives me: error C3861: 'glBindSampler': identifier not found. I am including "GLee.h" and "glut.h". In which .h file do I find glBindSampler?

Comment: Solved it. Include glew.h instead of GLee.h (and link with glew32.lib). It seems glew and GLee are mutually exclusive and doing the same thing, but glew is more up-to-date?